# Get menu object from theme_location

Tags: functions, menus, oop

I'd like to get a menu object from its theme location argument.

My goal is to output separately the menu name and its items name, url and description.

Example of what I'm looking for :

```
$menu = get_menu('nav-menu'); //get menu from its theme location
echo $menu->name; //displays the menu name
foreach($menu->items as $item){
    echo '<a href="'.$item->link'">'.$item->name.'</a>'; //displays a link to the item destination
    echo $item->description; //displays the item description
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This method looks like what you're looking for](http://www.andrewgail.com/getting-a-menu-name-in-wordpress/), using get_nav_menu_locations() and [get_term()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term/):

```
$theme_locations = get_nav_menu_locations();

$menu_obj = get_term( $theme_locations[$theme_location], 'nav_menu' );

$menu_name = $menu_obj->name;
```

(See the link for the whole thing wrapped up in a custom function; the above code just highlights the relevant WP functions for getting what you're after.)

Answer (score 4):

Or if you need it in one line, just copy that and replace "change-this-location-slug" by our own.

```
$string = get_term(get_nav_menu_locations()['change-this-location-slug'], 'nav_menu')->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

As of WordPress 3.0.0 you may use the `wp_get_nav_menu_object` function to retrieve the corresponding `WP_Term` to retrieve it's name.

Retrieving the id of the menu to pass to `wp_get_nav_menu_object` may be done via `get_nav_menu_locations`.

Expanding your example:

```php
$menu_id = get_nav_menu_locations()[ 'nav-menu' ];
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu_id );
$items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu_id );
 
echo $menu->name; // Displays the menu name.
foreach($items as $item){
    echo '<a href="'. esc_url( $item->url )'">'. esc_html( $item->title ).'</a>'; // Displays a link to the item destination.
    echo $item->description; // Displays the item description.
}
```