# How to conditionally add a wp_filter

Tags: theme-development, menus, filters

I have a WP filter I created that I only want to run on certain menu items.

I am attempting to use -

```
function add_nav_class($output) {
$output= preg_replace('/<a/', '<a class="lsbb"', $output, -1);
return $output;
}

function wp_nav_menu_conditionals() {
   if(!wp_nav_menu('theme_location' => 'footer_menu')) {
      add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'add_nav_class');
   }
}
add_action('wp', 'wp_nav_menu_conditionals');
```

I want to add_filter on all menus that are not listed as theme_location footer_menu. Is there a way to do this in WP? If the menu is using theme_location footer_menu I want it to NOT use add_filter.

Can anyone tell me how to use add_nav_class conditionally?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** -- fixed the `if()` statement.

```
function add_nav_class( $output ) {
    $menu_obj = get_term_by( 'slug', 'footer_menu', 'nav_menu' );

    // $menu_obj = get_term_by( 'name', 'Footer Menu', 'nav_menu' );
    // if the 'slug' version doesn't work, try the 'name' version
    // Just make sure you're using the correct name

    if( 'footer_menu' == $menu_obj->name ) ) {
        return $output; // bail if it's the 'footer_menu'
    }
    $output= preg_replace('/<a/', '<a class="lsbb"', $output, -1);
    return $output;
}

add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'add_nav_class');
```

**Edit 2** -- replaced `get_term()` with `get_term_by()`.

#### References

- Help from [this Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/29432/16121) from Chip Bennett
- [`get_term_by()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)

Comment: The if statement doesn't seem to work. If there a way to confirm that you can check the wp_nav_menu?

Comment: Updated -- try it now.

Comment: It didn't work. My footer menu is still making the change with the filter.

Comment: I did Print_r on the $menu_obj and it is empty.